# Is there a better, faster way to do this projectile motion question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

The question is

> In a combat exercise, a mortar at M is required to hit a target at O, which is taking cover 25 m behind a structure of negligible width 10 m tall. This mortar can only fire at an angle of 45 degrees to the horizontal, but can fire shells of any velocity. Find the minimum initial velocity required to hit the target.
>   [image: diagram]

I solved it as follows.

Forming a parabola with $ r_v $ against $ r_h $:

$ r_v = u_vt + \frac{1}{2}a_vt^{2} $ (1)

$ r_h = u_ht + \frac{1}{2}a_ht^{2} $

but $ a_h = 0 $

so $ r_h = u_ht $

$ t = \frac{r_h}{u_h} $ (2)

Substituting (2) into (1):

$ r_v = u_v\frac{r_h}{u_h} + \frac{1}{2}a_v\frac{r_h^{2}}{u_h^{2}} $ (3)

and because the angle of inclination is 45°

$ u_v = u_h = \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} $ (4)

From (4) and (3):

$ r_v = r_h^{2}\frac{a}{u^{2}} + r_h $ (5)

Let the distance between the mortar and the building be $ d $.

Then when $ r_h = d + 25 $, $ r_v = 0 $. (6)

From (5) and (6):

$ 0 = (d + 25)\frac{a}{u^{2}} + 1 $

so $ u^2 = -a(d + 25) $ (7)

Substituting (7) into (5):

$ r_v = -r_h^{2}\frac{1}{(d + 25)} + r_h $ (8)

We also know that to clear the building, when $ r_h = d $, $ r_v > 10 $. (9)

From (9) and (8):

$ 10 < -d^{2} \frac{1}{(d + 25)} + d $

After simplifying... ($ d + 25 $ is positive)

$ d > \frac{50}{3} $ (10)

Rearranging (7):

$ d = -\frac{u^{2}}{a} - 25 $ (11)

And then from (10) and (11) and with $ a = -9.8 $:

$ \frac{50}{3} < \frac{u^{2}}{9.8} - 25 $

Simplifying, and with the knowledge that $ u > 0 $:

$ u > 20.2073... $

So the minimum initial velocity required to hit the target is **20 m/s** (2 s. f.).

Huzzah!

My question is: **is there a faster way to solve the problem?**

Comment: Really [fast](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%3D%28t+v%29%2Fsqrt%282%29-9.8+t%5E2%2C+25%3D%28t+v%29%2Fsqrt%282%29) (not using your variables, just stuff I made up), but I'm getting an initial velocity $28.5774$ that is $\sqrt{2}$ times larger. Did I make a mistake or did you?

Comment: You did: that -9.8t^2 term should be -4.9t^2. (r = ut + (1/2)at^2)

Comment: Ah, a little bit too fast then. I wonder if there's a known exoplanet where my formula _does_ hold. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this is any faster is debatable, but you could do it this way:

The trajectory of the shell is symmetric, so $M$ firing a shell at $O$ is the same as $O$ firing a shell at $M$. So all you have to do is consider $O$ firing the mortar at 45° and ask what is the minimum velocity required to clear the wall. So, if $O$ fires the shell at 45° the equations of motion are:

$$\begin{align}
x &= t \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} \\
y &= t \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} g t^2
\end{align}$$

If we require that the trajectory passes through the point $(25, 10)$ then this gives us two simultaneous equations in $t$ and $v$:

$$\begin{align}
25 &= t \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} \\
10 &= t \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} g t^2
\end{align}$$

It's $v$ we're interested in, so we rearrange the first equation to get:

$$ t = \frac{25\sqrt{2}}{v} $$

and substitute it in the second equation to get:

$$ 10 = \frac{25\sqrt{2}}{v} \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} g \left( \frac{25\sqrt{2}}{v} \right)^2 $$

and a quick rearrangement gives:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{g \space 25^2}{15}} = 20.2 m/s $$

Comment: Very nice. I considered this at some stage; I don't know why I never revisited it. This is probably the fastest way to do it. I wonder what the fastest way is if you still consider M firing from O.